# How to combine the WHERE Clause in SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How could I make this query better?

```
SELECT ClientID, BatchID, jobid, subjobid, count(clientid) as Total 
FROM data with(nolock) 
WHERE batchid in (select BatchID from data with(nolock) where lookupcode = '111111111111') 
and clientid in (select ClientID from data with(nolock) where lookupcode = '111111111111') 
and jobid in (select jobid from data with(nolock) where lookupcode = '111111111111') 
and subjobid in (select subjobid from data with(nolock) where lookupcode = '111111111111') 
and entrytype <> 'C'
and entrytype <> 'M'
group by clientid,BatchID, jobid, subjobid
```

Comment: 'better' is very subjective.  Do you mean you want this query to perform better? do you want it to be more readable?  Do you want it to be more portable?

Comment: Perform better, i think that having the same query in 4 different parts of the where clause cant be good

Comment: I think we're confused, because we don't have enough information.  You may have the perfect query already, or you may not.  Can you share the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: The table has fields batchid, jobid, subjobid which are not unique, they have multiple rows. The unique identifier is the lookupcode. So if i have a lookupcode i can get the batch, job, subjob it came from then query using that information to get the rest of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a CTE:

```
WITH lookup AS (
    select ClientID, BatchID, JobID, SubJobID 
    from data with(nolock) 
    where lookupcode = '111111111111'
)
SELECT ClientID, BatchID, jobid, subjobid, count(clientid) as Total 
FROM data with(nolock) 
WHERE batchid in (select BatchID from lookup) 
and clientid in (select ClientID from lookup) 
and jobid in (select jobid from lookup) 
and subjobid in (select subjobid from lookup) 
and entrytype not in ('C', 'M')
group by clientid,BatchID, jobid, subjobid
```

Your original solution however does not implement the condition you state in the comments:

> find all rows that have the same batch
>   job and subjob

since you do not check for the combination of job and subjob.

If you need to combine some fields for exact matches, try a condition like this

```
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM lookup 
    WHERE lookup.jobid = data.jobid AND lookup.subjobid = data.subjobid
)
```

Since we don't have a table structure and sample data, it's hard for us to check whether our solutions are correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ClientID, BatchID, jobid, subjobid, count(clientid) as Total 
from data with (nolock) 
where lookupcode = '111111111111'
    and entrytype not in ('C', 'M')
group by clientid, BatchID, jobid, subjobid
```

**Update:**

```
select d2.ClientID, d2.BatchID, d2.jobid, d2.subjobid, count(*) as Total  
from data with (nolock)  d1
inner join data d2 on d1.batchjobid = d2.batchjobid 
    and d1.subjobid = d2.subjobid
where d1.lookupcode = '111111111111' 
    and d2.entrytype not in ('C', 'M') 
group by clientid, BatchID, jobid, subjobid
```

Comment: That only gets one row, i need to get all of the rows inside the querys in the where clause.

Comment: I do not follow, please provide sample data and output.

Comment: I guess i should have been more specific, i need to find all rows that have the same batch job and subjob as the one barcode. This answer only gets me that information for just one record not all

Comment: Your query gives me

6119 22849 1 1 1

my query gives me

6119 22849 1 1 306


notice the count is the improtant field...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this.

```
SELECT d1.clientid, d1.BatchID, d1.jobid, d1.subjobid, count(clientid) as Total 
FROM data with(nolock) as d1
join (
    select BatchID, ClientID, jobid, subjobid 
    from data with(nolock) 
    where lookupcode = '111111111111'
) as d2
WHERE d1.batchid = d2.BatchID 
and d1.clientid = d2.clientid
and d1.jobid = d2.jobid
and d1.subjobid d2.subjobid
and d1.entrytype <> 'C'
and d1.entrytype <> 'M'
group by d1.clientid, d1.BatchID, d1.jobid, d1.subjobid
```